# adding method to object in chrome console

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I am trying to add a method to an object using Chrome's javascript console, but the function does not show up along with the other properties which I enter the object. Should the method be showing up using the code below?

For example,I created obj2 and added increaseAge method:

```
obj2 = {
firstName:'Albert',
lastName:'Jones',
age:8,
increaseAge:function(){
this.age++;
}
}
```

But when I entered obj2, the method doesn't show up. When I try to call it with obj2.increaseAge() the console says `undefined`.

The results of the console:

```
Object {firstName: "Albert", lastName: "Jones", age: 8}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

Your method should return the value for you to see it

```
increaseAge:function(){
   return this.age++;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but why does it return 8 instead of 9? Wouldn't it add one to the age value 8?

Comment: @st4rgut If you apply the increment (++) operator before the variable, it will increment the value first and then will return. Above code first returns and then increments the age variable.

Comment: Yes, @jahnestacado is right here. You can use `return ++(this.age);` if you want the incremented value to be returned.